# How to set image path on image view in android

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-json

I have the following code in which i am getting id , name and image path.

i want to show that image path in image view.

```
public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

    String pid;


    private ProgressDialog pDialog;


    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products =      "example.com/files/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
    private static final String TAG_IMAGE1 = "image1";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // getting product details from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // getting product id (pid) from intent
        pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        EditProductActivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }


        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", pid));
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET",
                    params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String price = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);
                        String image1 = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE1);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_PRICE, price);
                        map.put(TAG_IMAGE1, image1);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products

            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_row, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_NAME, TAG_PRICE, TAG_IMAGE1 },
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.price,
                                    R.id.thumbnail });

                    // updating Listview

                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

i have pass the `image1` path in list adapter and i have taken imageview in .xml file.

But i didnt get ant images over their.

```
list_row.xml containg image view:


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />
```

How can i show images in imageview?

Comment: In AsyncTask [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)) run in UI thread, runOnUiThread is not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going to work with JSON,
And load image from server,

If yes than I will suggest you to use any image loader like universal-image loader.

[Universal image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Answer (score 1):

[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) download the image in another thread and it manages for you:

- the placeholder in the meantime the image is still downloading
- resizing
- cropping/centering/scaling
- caching ( you don't have to download the image every time)
- it even does "image fade in", which is popular/normal now

It's extremely simple, here is an example:

```
Picasso.with(context)
       .load(url)
       .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
       .resize(imgWidth, imgHeight)
       .centerCrop()
       .into(image);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the following steps :

1)You need to implement a custom adapter that will fill image by lazy loading the image as per corresponding URL on that row

2)Implement a LazyLoader that can download an image and refresh imageview when completed

3)Call LazyLoading when the getView Method of your custom adapter is called

4)Call your Custom adapter in OnPostExecute , instead of your Listadapter

5)OR to make the LazyLoading part easier , you code use the [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom Adapter, inflate your row layout and retrieve your ImageView from the layout. Then you can set your ImageView programmatically like :

```
File imgFile = new  File(yourImagePath);
if(imgFile.exists()){
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    yourImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
}
```

A tutorial to create your own adapter : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Download picasso jar file and add in android build application jar first:

and now just get your url from json

if(response.login_data.avtar!=null &&response.login_data.avtar.length()>0) {

```
                        String photo=response.login_data.avtar.toString();

                        infoLog("avatar"+photo);
                        String url=App.WEB_PHOTO_URL+photo;
                        infoLog("avatar url"+url);
                    Picasso.with(HealthProfile.this).load(url).into(img);

                    }

                    else {

    Picasso.with(HealthProfile.this).load(R.drawable.user).into(img);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.animage);
  Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
  if (imageUri != null) {
            String filePath = null;
            filePath = imageUri.getPath();
           BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
           options.inSampleSize = 8;
           Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath,options);
           imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **Picasso** lib, a powerful image downloading and caching library for Android.

It provides a super clean syntax so that you can use it having none of confusion.

For example, in your adapter, you an try like this :

First, if you use **SimpleAdapter**, **ViewBinder** is what you should know. Details see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder.html

Then, in **setViewValue** of your own ViewBinder, just add the code below:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(img_path).into(imgView)
```

Or if you custom your own adapter, add the code in your **getView** function that is override.

Finally, it show images on your imageviews.

More details about Picasso : http://square.github.io/picasso/

**Universal Image Loader** is your another choice, which also having numbers of users. It is more customizable. See : https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 0):

Too late but maybe it can help someone.

**If you are ok using some image loading library in your project, just use this custom image view to allow setting url from xml.**

As you can set url from xml, it is possible to directly bind your link variable to imageview.

Create custom image view.

```
class MyImageView : ImageView {

var url: String = ""
    set(value){
        field = value
        Glide.with(this).load(value).into(this)
    }

constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

constructor(context: Context, attrs : AttributeSet) : super(context,attrs){
    val array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyImageView)
    val url = array.getString(R.styleable.MyImageView_url)

    if(url!=null){
        Glide.with(this).load(url).into(this)
    }

    array.recycle()
}

constructor(context: Context,  attrs: AttributeSet , defStyleAttr : Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
```

}

Add this in attr.xml

```
<declare-styleable name="MyImageView">
    <attr name="url" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Use it in xml

```
<package.path.MyImageView
         android:id="@+id/image_company_logo"
         android:scaleType="fitCenter"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="80dp"
         android:contentDescription="logo"
         app:url="@{invoice.invoiceLogoLink}"/>  //for data binding purpose
```

Find out more about it [here](https://github.com/amit-bhandari/CustomImageView)